# Ext JavaScript database

Tags: database, extjs4

Is there any specific and supporting database server for Ext Js?

Otherwise, what is the best database used in ExtJS applications normally? My application looks [like this](http://www.uploadscreenshot.com/image/787881/9481883).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a server side technology that can retrieve data from your existing database. The database itself is not important since you will be writing a server side application layer that will abstract that interaction.

My recommendation on the server side application implementation is any framework that can easily turn your relational (or not) data into JSON format for consumption by your ExtJS application. 
I use Grails and am very happy with it, especially how easy it is to work with JSON and feed it to ExtJS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific database, which is convenient to use according to your requirement. For static use, like combo boxes, you can have [Ext.data.Store](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-1.1.1/docs/output/Ext.data.Store.html)